# Vue.js Axios delete method deleting the wrong object in the array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have an issue where my axios.delete method is deleting the wrong objects in the array. There are 3 objects total, coming from an api, the objects with id 2 and 3 fine when I delete in the index.html file, but it throws a 'Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404' error when I try to delete the first object in the array coming from my API.

My index file (includes the delete button)

```
 <body>
        <div id="app">
          <template v-for="(results, index) in result">

              <div  class="card" style="width: 20rem; display:inline-block;">
                <div class="card-block">
                 <p>{{ results }}</p>

                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-toggle="modal" v-on:submit.prevent="deleteData(index)" @click="deleteData(results, index) in result">Delete</button>

                 <h1> {{ results.comments}} </h1>

              </div>
              </div>

            </template>

        </div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script src="src/main.js"></script>
```

Main.js

```
var vm = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    result: ''
  },

  created: function(){
    this.getResult();
  },

  methods: {

    deleteData: function(result, id) {
      axios.delete('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/json/posts/' + id)
      .then(response => {
        this.result.splice(id, 1)
        console.log(this.result);
      });
    },

    getResult: function() {
      // this.results = 'Loading...';
      axios.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/json/db')
      .then(response => {
        // console.log(response.data);
        this.result = response.data.posts;
        console.log(this.result);
      });
    }
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as I can see, you pass two params to your `deleteData` method. the second param it's the index of results array it's not your real id of results.

here, you just need to replace your `deleteData` method by this :

```
 deleteData: function(result, id) {
      axios.delete('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/json/posts/' + result.id)
      .then(response => {
        this.result.splice(id, 1)
        console.log(this.result);
      });
    },
```

as you can see above,we have just changed your `id` by `result.id`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-toggle="modal" v-on:submit.prevent="deleteData(index)" @click="deleteData(results, index) in result">Delete</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-toggle="modal" @click="deleteData(results, index)">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a 404 error meaning the it's unable to the page. It might be the link is incorrect. Please look at the url once again! The same thing happened with me, then I realized the URL which I was trying to reach was incorrect.

Comment: As you can see, this question is already answered, and your solution has nothing to do with the real problem in it...